# Incorrect badge icon in notifications

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, notifications

I just got a badge on Meta SO, but got the notification while I was browsing Sci-Fi and Fantasy. The notification looked like this when viewing from that site:

[image: wrong badge!]

Last time I checked, meta SO badges were still circles :). The notification *does* appear correctly when viewed on meta SO itself.

The bug affects other sites, on Arqade it uses their badge icon in the notification just as it did on Sci-Fi.

Comment: Does this only happen on sites whose badges are non-generic circles?  Maybe bit more relevant to MSE?

Comment: I know I've seen this pop up before, but I don't remember where. I vaguely remember it being by-design, however.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Not sure. I don't get badges often enough to know :(

Comment: Found them! [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233517/badge-symbol-in-notification-is-of-the-site-youre-on-not-where-badge-was-earne) and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259984/notifications-for-badges-on-other-stack-exchange-sites-use-the-wrong-badge-icon) on MSE address it- No actual status tags, though.

Comment: Well, hopefully someone will ad [meta-tag:status-bydesign] soon then...