# Tag badge icons should correspond to the site they were earned on

Tags: feature-request, design, badges, achievements-dialog

Badges in the achievements dialog should be relevant to the site they were earned on, not the site in which you are currently on.

Note that I am currently on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ but the badge that I earned was from https://stackoverflow.com/

[image: Tag badge image]

Can this be changed so that the badge is relevant to the site it was earned on?

---

The [mentioned dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300783/incorrect-badge-icon-in-notifications) is asking if this behaviour is a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug). I am asking it as a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) therefore I believe it not to be a dupe.

Also the [cross site dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233517/badge-symbol-in-notification-is-of-the-site-youre-on-not-where-badge-was-earne) has had no official response as of yet so I believe it is still okay to ask this here.

Comment: You mean…you want them to load *all* of those sprites? Think of the children!

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269324/can-all-site-specific-badge-images-be-shown-on-all-profile-pages/269350#269350 and full dupe on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233517/badge-symbol-in-notification-is-of-the-site-youre-on-not-where-badge-was-earne

Comment: It doesn't much matter what the tags are. A feature request is a just a bug wearing lipstick.